# Shortcut to make something readonly/not readonly

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, read-only

Is there a windows (explorer) shortcut or non-mouse oriented command to make a toggle a given file's read only status?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works under XP:
<kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> <kbd>Alt+R</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Additionally confirmed to work under Windows 7

Comment: Continues to work under Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

[`attrib`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) is what you're looking for:

```
attrib +r readonlyfile.txt
attrib -r writeablefile.txt
```

`help attrib` says:

```
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [drive:][path][filename]
       [/S [/D]]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
```

Comment: Good answer, though it made me revise my original question because I really wanted a windows explorer shortcut.  I'm thinking one doesn't exist, but maybe someone knows of an shell extension or something.

Comment: Perhaps using a combination of `attrib` and the *Send To* folder would solve your problem.

Comment: You can also add a verb to the context menu which toggles it.